# Action Bar doesn't appear in latest update of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar

After latest update of the Android Studio, the ActionBar doesn't appear in the preview screen. I reloaded the program several times, but it didn't help. Also, the text on the button looks a bit weird, but that isn't the main issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukFMr.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I just needed to enable "Show Layout Decorations", but rendering problem hasn't gone [rendering problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM34J.png)